# ptxas complains about (types in) my sad device function

Tags: cuda, ptx

Consider the following PTX code:

```
//
// Generated by NVIDIA NVVM Compiler... sort of
//
// Compiler Build ID: CL-25769353
// Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.105
// Based on LLVM 3.4svn
//

.version 6.4
.target sm_30
.address_size 64

.func  (.param .b32 func_retval0) foo(
        .param .b32 foo_param_0,
        .param .b32 foo_param_1,
        .param .b32 foo_param_2
)
{
        .reg .b16       %rs<3>;
        .reg .b32       %r<3>;


        ld.param.u16    %rs1, [foo_param_0];
        ld.param.u16    %rs2, [foo_param_1];
        ld.param.u32    %r2, [foo_param_2];
        // inline asm
        sad.s16 %r1, %rs1, %rs2, %r2;
        // inline asm
        st.param.b32    [func_retval0+0], %r1;
        ret;
}
```

When trying to compile this with ptxas (CUDA 10.1), I get:

```
ptxas /tmp/a.ptx, line 27; error   : Arguments mismatch for instruction 'sad'
ptxas fatal   : Ptx assembly aborted due to errors
```

why is that? What's wrong with this combination of types?

The [PTX reference](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html) says:

> ```
> sad.type  d, a, b, c;
>
> .type = { .u16, .u32, .u64,
>           .s16, .s32, .s64 };
> ```

and it seems `d` and `c` are `u32` always and `type` applies to `a` and `b`. That's what the `__sad()` functions in `device_functions.h` have anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the type of `d` and `a` needs to be "the unsigned version of the type of `b` and `c`". So, this should work:

```
.func  (.param .b32 func_retval0) foo(
        .param .b32 foo_param_0,
        .param .b32 foo_param_1,
        .param .b32 foo_param_2
)
{
        .reg .b32       %r<5>;


        ld.param.u32    %r4, [foo_param_2];
        ld.param.s16    %r2, [foo_param_0];
        ld.param.s16    %r3, [foo_param_1];
        // inline asm
        sad.s32 %r1, %r2, %r3, %r4;
        // inline asm
        st.param.b32    [func_retval0+0], %r1;
        ret;
}
```